# BOOL variable behaves like it is NO when it actually is YES iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to objective-c and it seems to be very strange. I don't want to enable a method if a BOOL variable named "isFirstWordBeingAnimated" is equal to YES.

the variable isFirstWordBeingAnimated is equal to NO and for some reason it is treated as YES:
[image]

note that when I place the mouse on top of that variable meanwhile debugging xcode tells me that isFirstWordBeingAnimated is equal to NO. Why is it that the returns block gets executed !?

Moreover, I have set isFirstWordBeingAnimated=YES only on once of my code with a breackpoint:
[image]

I have not reached that breakpoint and xCode thinks it is equal to YES and I set that variable equal to NO when the view did loaded. Why is this?

Could it be because I have not defined the getters and setters? I defined isFirstWordBeingAnimated at the top of my .m file without creating the mutator (setter) and accessor (getter) methods...

---

EDIT

I have changed my code:

[image]

[image]

and I get the same problem:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to debug with optimizations enabled (i.e. are you debugging the Release build)?  If so, the debugger is lying to you.

Comment: How do I know that? it makes no sense. I think xCode should debug the build that is interacting with my iPad. But it will be nice if you are right. How can I check that?

Comment: Go to Product > Edit Scheme... and in the "Info" tab the Build Configuration will either be Debug or Release. Breakpoints are active in both, but GDB info is usually misleading if your building for Release.

Comment: when I don't debug the application behaves just like I expect it to work so I assume it is probably what you are saying. Thanks a lot. post that answer and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no need to use `isFirstWordBeingAnimated == YES`.  Just stick the boolean in the parentheses and it will be evaluated for true or false.  Secondly, you created the getter/setter fine but you're not actually using it.  If you wanted to refer to the boolean or set it, use `self.isFirstWordBeingAnimated`.

On your problem, though, a boolean is always false unless you explicitly set it to true.  In your case I believe the problem lies in the fact that your boolean is never created - thus making it false.  If you wouldn't mind more code would help to understand exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

First I would create a property in your header-file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter= isFirstWordBeingAnimated) BOOL firstWordBeingAnimated;
```

Also add to your main-file:

```
@synthesize firstWordBeingAnimated;
```

Next I don't like to use `if(isEnabled)
return;`

Better you put brackets around `return;`

```
if (isEnabled) {
     return;
}
```

---

Try `if (isEnbabled)` instead of `if (isEnabled==YES)`, I won't change anything, but I have no other ideas.